# How to know the origin of the remote repository?

Tags: git, openshift

I am trying to update the codes in ssh://xxxxx@idating1-idating1.rhcloud.com/~/git/idating1.git, which is given by openshift for project idating1. But due to some reasons, my mac cannot setup rhc properly. I successfully git clone the source code. How can I push changes of the code to ssh://xxxx@idating1-idating1.rhcloud.com/~/git/idating1.git?  I don't know what the name of the origin is.

Comment: just say `git remote` or `git remote -v`

Comment: You need to provide concrete details.  What do you try, what happens, what did you think should happen, why you think that.

Answer (score 2):

You need `git remote -v | grep /part/of/the/url` to get the name of the remote upstream repo. (See [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote))

You also can see it in a `git config --local -l`

If you don't want to do  a grep, [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) can do it for you:

```
git config --get-regexp remote.* b2d

remote.origin.url https://VonC@github.com/VonC/b2d.git
       ^^^^^^
          |
          --- name of the remote, for an url including "b2d"
```

That will grep for any `remote.*` key, with any value including part of the repo url (here, just its name in this example)

---

If git remote -v returns nothing, then no remote is set locally.
To add one:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote add origin /url/to/remote/repo
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: It does not work. The system I use is OS X. It returns nothing. Can you tell me what code to write in terminal to get the origin of the remote git repository? The only thing that I know is the url of the repository.

Comment: @michaelsgx if it returns nothing at all, that means you havbe no remote set: simply set one: `git remote add origin /url/of/remote/repo`

Comment: @michaelsgx if you have clone the repo, a `git remote -v` should not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Repo's don't have intrinsic names -- they don't even have intrinsic urls.  There is only how you refer to them this time.

You can see what names a remote repository has for its own remotes with `git ls-remote u://r/l`, but I'm pretty sure there's no way to discover what url's it uses for them.

What name you use for a remote is utterly arbitrary.  `origin` is just a handy conventional name for the remote set up by clone.

You don't even need a name at all; for one-off pushing and fetching you can use the url directly.